# Gradle doesn't load 0.9.8 version library

Tags: androidplot

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/2', 'src/main/java/com/example/user/myapplication/function']
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:0.9.8'
}
```

this is my code.
Gradle doesn't load 0.9.8 version library. However when I use 0.6.1 library it can load. I want to use latest version. What's the problem?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I solved this problem when I updated new android studio! the problem was  that library class couldn't load in java and xml.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone for whom updating did not work, when I had this problem I discovered that it was because I did not have

```
mavenCentral()
```

in the project level build.gradle file (under allprojects and repositories).